# How to use a custom background on grouped UITableView cells?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, user-interface

I am trying to set a custom background for the rows of a grouped `UITableView` and I have absolutely no idea how to achieve that.

The table design I am trying to apply on my table looks like this:

[image: Custom Designed Grouped UITableView]

And I have sliced it into 3 cell types: **top**, **middle** and **bottom**. How can I apply the custom background for each of the table's cells?

Comment: how you solve it? do you have any source ?

Answer (score 6):

You can set `UIImageView` as cell `backgroundView` for first, middle and last cell in function:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell  forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Check good (and simple) example at:
http://www.planet1107.net/blog/tips-tutorials/custom-grouped-cell-tutorial/

Answer (score 4):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, check the type of current row and then assign the corresponding background to it.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //  Create cell
    //  ...

    //  Configure cell

    switch (cellType)  {
       case TOP:
           cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top.png"]];  
           break;
       case MIDDLE:
           ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this method but after I set the cell's backgroundView nothing displays, and the table remains unstyled with its default background. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Ray Wenderlich has a very good tutorial on how to do this with Core Graphics: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2033/core-graphics-101-lines-rectangles-and-gradients

Comment: Looks great, I'll check it out today and post here if it works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial will give you exactly what you're looking for.

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Comment: I have tried this method but after I set the cell's backgroundView nothing displays, and the table remains unstyled with its default background. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewCell has an property backgroundView. Set this value in your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:-method.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning separate image for each, Create one custom cell and assign background image as cell has above. And Crop above image other than inner cells assign that one to UITableView's background view (Plain table view) i.e you dont need to create grouped table view.